# How to specify which margin a glyph renders to?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2017, visual-studio-sdk, visual-studio-2019

The code snippets from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/extensibility/walkthrough-creating-a-margin-glyph?view=vs-2017 walk you through creating a margin glyph, implementing `TaggerProvider` / `ITagger<T>` and a `GlyphFactoryProvider` / `GlyphFactory`. This renders the glyph to the same margin where breakpoints appear.

I want to create a custom margin, but use the built-in Glyph/Tagger logic for managing that Glyph's position, etc. How can I create a relationship between the Glyph / Tagger objects and an `IWpfTextViewMarginProvider` / `IWpfTextViewMargin`?